# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I have PHP SOAP server which is communicate with another SOAP servers as a SOAP client. I have used nusoap library.

The SOAP server is working fine when traffic is low. But when server request incenses, we have received error for some of the requests

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/public_html/api/soapserver.php:

Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://100.20.5...', 'urn:NameSpc#Fin...', 1, 0)

1 /home/public_html/api/soapserver.php (103): SoapClient->__soapCall('FindClient...', Array)

2 [internal function]: FindClientInfo('username', 'password')

3 /home/public_html/api/lib/nusoap.php(4206): call_user_func_array('FindClient...', Array)

4 /home/public_html/api/lib/nusoap.php(3828): nusoap_server->invoke_method()

5 /home/public_html/api/soapserver.php(25): nusoap_server->service('<?xml version="...')

6 {main}
```

PHP Version is 5.4.45

Id: nusoap.php,v 1.123 2010/04/26 20:15:08 snichol Exp

Please suggest with necessary way to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.